# How do you load a WAV file with Sound.loadPCMFromByteArray()?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, arrays, pcm

Based on the resource [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) (defining the **structure of a WAV file**), I was able to get the audio data between the 44th byte and near the end of the file (some extra meta-data exists at the end which is not necessary).

But I'm having trouble loading it with the new `Sound.loadPCMFromByteArray()` method available in Flash Player 11.

I get this error if I pass the number of samples:

```
_sound.loadPCMFromByteArray(pcm, pcm.length, "float", wav.isStereo, wav.sampleRate);
```

- **[Fault] exception, information=ArgumentError: Error #2084: The AMF encoding of the arguments cannot exceed 40K**

However, if I divide the `pcm.length` by four (4), it seems to play "something" but isn't at all the sample that I passed it originally. Plus, it sounds like it's **looping** forever, is this the intended behavior? (*I sure hope not!*)

```
 //Dividing by 4 (# >> 2 is the same) is playable, but incorrect!
 _sound.loadPCMFromByteArray(pcm, pcm.length >> 2, "float", wav.isStereo, wav.sampleRate);
```

Does the ByteArray of WAV data need to be processed a certain way to conform to a readable PCM format? Do I need to insert an **EOF** character at the end so it knows when to stop the Sound file?

Should I use another format than *"float"*? Which ones are supported?

Comment: if the playback is funny, then I suspect that the the format of data is not what FP is expecting it to be. This function assumes 32bits/sample. I guess if your original file is encoded in something different, then you'd need to pre-process the data before passing it on to loadPCMFromByteArray

Comment: it has something to do with "short" instead of "float". I will provide an elaborate answer later...

Comment: @bigp - were you able to accomplish this? Also, there are classes out there to save and load WAV files in Flash. Have you tried these?

Comment: Hey gigawatts, No I wasn't able to successfully load PCM data. I gave up on this method after a few other developers reported the issue to Adobe and their response didn't seem like they considered it a high-priority (which sucks!). For the time being, I used Andre Michelle's Popforge library which works well enough to create SWF-Sound files at runtime. The loadPCMFromByteArray(...) method might be fixed when AS4 comes out, lets hope!

Comment: I think the classes you speak of are the ones in the Popforge library, yeah I gave those a try. What I'm mostly interested in though is create audio-processing algorithms. So working with raw PCM ByteArrays would be much faster (in theory).